# Add logon program for TSclients in environment tab user adsi in Powershell

Tags: powershell, adsi, terminal-services, iadstsuserex

Hi I'm tring to set a logon program parameter for remote clients that will be created using a powershell script. As shown below

[image]

I managed to get a logon script to set in the profile tab using

```
$objUser.PSBase.InvokeSet('LoginScript', "logoff.cmd")
```

As seed in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778973/assign-logon-scripts-to-local-users)

The problem is I can't find the attribes in ADSIedit also some attrribes that I use and work aren't shown in ADSIedit such as PasswordExpired

which leads me to believe the attribute does exsist. Below is my code

```
$objComputer = [ADSI]"WinNT://127.0.0.1"
$objUser = $objComputer.Create('user', $username)
$objUser.SetPassword($password)
$objUser.PSBase.InvokeSet('Description', "user " + $userName)
$objUser.PSBase.InvokeSet('userflags', 512)
$objUser.PSBase.InvokeSet('passwordExpired', 1)
$objUser.SetInfo();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a long time to figure this one out be found the answer in [IADsTSUserEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380823%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) library

here is the code below

```
# adds user
$objComputer = [ADSI]"WinNT://127.0.0.1"
$objUser = $objComputer.Create('user', $username)
$objUser.SetPassword($password)
$objUser.PSBase.InvokeSet('Description', "user " + $userName)
$objUser.PSBase.InvokeSet('userflags', 512)
$objUser.SetInfo();
# set password not to expire
wmic USERACCOUNT WHERE "Name = '$username'" SET Passwordexpires=FALSE
#set logoff script
$ou = [adsi]"WinNT://127.0.0.1"
$user = $ou.psbase.get_children().find("test")
$user.PSBase.InvokeSet("TerminalServicesInitialProgram", "C:\logoff.bat")
$user.setinfo()
```